# Create Div and Append inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main container div, and a sidebar div. When clicking one of the sidebar divs, i want to create a div that is inside the container div.  Here is what i have so far.

```
    <script>

$(function() {
$( "#container" ).sortable();
$( "#container" ).disableSelection();
});

function popUp(){
    var popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.className = 'box3';

</script>

<ul id="container" style="position:relative;width:815;height:870;margin:20px;background-color:gray;">

    <li class="box2"></li>




</ul>
<div style="position:absolute;top:20;left:850;height:870px;width:320px;background-color:yellow;padding-left:15px;float:left;">
    <div id="add3" class="box3" style="height:15%;width:40%;" onclick="popup()" >Click Me to Add</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="add2" class="box2" style="height:15%;width:80%;">Click Me to Add</div>
</div>
```

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Also, your inline handler reads `popup()` and your actual function name is `popUp`. And you might want to swap the inline for jQuery event listeners.

Comment: You container is a UL, so it is not valid to insert divs directly into that element. please clarify where they are to be added.

Comment: That honestly slipped my mind, yea it would be creating a <li> and putting it into a list upon clicking

Comment: Have updated final example to us LI instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like:

```
function popUp(){
    $('<div>').addClass('box3').appendTo('#container');
}
```

Where `$('<div>')` uses jQuery to create a new DIV element, which has a class added, then it is appended to the container*.

You should attached the click listener in code as well (get rid of the `onClick=`):

```
$('#add3').click(function(){
        $('<div>').addClass('box3').appendTo('#container');
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/K269E/3/

So your full code winds up something like:

```
$(function () {
    $("#container").sortable();
    $("#container").disableSelection();

    $('#add3').click(function () {
        $('<div>').addClass('box3').appendTo('#container');
    });
});
```

*You have nothing in the new div of course, but you have not specified what you want to do next with it*

### Update to use an LI: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/K269E/7/

```
$('<li>').addClass('box3').text("hello").appendTo('#container');
```

This one will add new LIs to your container UL (that simply says "hello" as an example).

### Note:

You are wanting to inject a `DIV` into a `UL` (`id=container`), which is not valid HTML markup. You need to be a little clearer about the intended use.

Comment: Not quite what im looking for but should be able to work with it, i need to create a complete new div instead of just moving the previous one

Comment: This is creating a new div.... That's what $('<div>') does - inject HTML elements (sorry I fixed my typos in the sample - was missing the all-important `<>`) :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to move a nested DIV from sidebar into container using javascript.

*Consider the following `div` structure:*

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <div id="minidiv1">a</div>
   <div id="minidiv2">b</div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

To accomplish this I can simply append `minidiv1` to the `container`, and it will change its location in the DOM:

```
$('#minidiv1').appendTo('#container'); 
// or
$('#container').append('#minidiv1');
```

The difference between the above two lines is what is returned, appendTo returns the `#minidiv1` element, append will return the `#container` element.